# How to draw an arc with rounded corners?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am using D3 to create a circle arc but I want to draw that arc with rounded corners.

Below is the screenshot of my arc:

[image]

What I want is to set the round corner on both sides of this arc like below:

[image]

The full source code is:

```
var tau = 2 * Math.PI; // http://tauday.com/tau-manifesto

// An arc function with all values bound except the endAngle. So, to compute an
// SVG path string for a given angle, we pass an object with an endAngle
// property to the `arc` function, and it will return the corresponding string.
var arc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(80)
    .outerRadius(140)
    .startAngle(0);

// Get the SVG container, and apply a transform such that the origin is the
// center of the canvas. This way, we don’t need to position arcs individually.
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

// Add the background arc, from 0 to 100% (tau).
var background = g.append("path")
    .datum({endAngle: tau})
    .style("fill", "#ddd")
    .attr("d", arc);

// Add the foreground arc in orange, currently showing 12.7%.
var foreground = g.append("path")
    .datum({endAngle: 0.627 * tau})
    .style("fill", "#e90b3a")
    .attr("d", arc);
```

CodePen is here:https://codepen.io/zhaoyi0113/pen/PEgYZX

Comment: @MichaelMullany Look at the desired outcome and also at my answer. This is clearly **not** a duplicate: OP chose the wrong title for describing it, that's all.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for the correction. I'll undo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question's title is misleading: what you want is to round the corners of that path.

That being said, use `cornerRadius`:

```
var arc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(80)
    .outerRadius(140)
    .startAngle(0)
    .cornerRadius(30);
```

So, in this case, I'm using `30`, which is `(outerRadius - innerRadius)/2`.

Here is your code with that change only:

```js
var tau = 2 * Math.PI; // http://tauday.com/tau-manifesto

// An arc function with all values bound except the endAngle. So, to compute an
// SVG path string for a given angle, we pass an object with an endAngle
// property to the `arc` function, and it will return the corresponding string.
var arc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(80)
    .outerRadius(140)
    .startAngle(0)
    .cornerRadius(30);


// Get the SVG container, and apply a transform such that the origin is the
// center of the canvas. This way, we don’t need to position arcs individually.
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

// Add the background arc, from 0 to 100% (tau).
var background = g.append("path")
    .datum({endAngle: tau})
    .style("fill", "#ddd")
    .attr("d", arc);

// Add the foreground arc in orange, currently showing 12.7%.
var foreground = g.append("path")
    .datum({endAngle: 0.627 * tau})
    .style("fill", "#e90b3a")
    .attr("d", arc);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
```